# How to clear session variable on timer elapsed and redirect to another view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer, session-variables

I am using System.Timers.Timer class. The logic is to trigger timer via Elapsed after 5 minutes. After interval elapses(say after 5 minutes), I want to clear session variables that are to be disposed and redirect to another view.

I know that main thread and interval elapsed thread are two different thread and therefore, I am not able to access session. But I am bound by the requirement to clear session and redirect to another view after this interval.

I also thought of using JavaScript timeout functionality but I suspect this won't help me because my app calls another API(payment gateway API) and the URL will be redirected to their URL page. So, checking onto DOM, I see only their html page content and my content will come afterwards when the post into my url from their server.(By this time, javascript timer will already be gone)

My code is:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    { 
        TimerSessionForIssueTicket();
        return View();
    }

    public void TimerSessionForIssueTicket()
    {
        FlightBooking FlightBooking = new FlightBooking(); 

        if (Session["Timer"] == null)
            Session["Timer"] = new Timer();

        ((Timer)Session["Timer"]).Interval = FlightBooking.GetTicketBookingIssueTime((string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TicketBookingWindowTotal"]);
        ((Timer)Session["Timer"]).Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        ((Timer)Session["Timer"]).AutoReset = false;
        ((Timer)Session["Timer"]).Enabled = true;
    }


    private void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {            
        CancelBooking();
    }

    public ActionResult CancelBooking()
    {
        if (Session["Inbound"] != null) { Session.Remove("Inbound"); }
        return View("Index", home);
    }
```

When timer elapsed, session threw system.nullreferenceexception. 
I removed code to remove session in order to check for page redirect, but no error came and page did not redirect.

How can I fix this issue? OR are there any other techniques to accomplish this task? Please suggest

Comment: Once the page is loaded, the browser just has some HTML. The browser doesn't know that a timer running on the server exists. If you want to redirect the user after five minutes you would need to do that from the client using JavaScript or meta tags.

Comment: Scott, I have added my sample code below based on your reply..

Answer (score 0):

My code is going to be something like this. Once page is redirected to google.com, Timer will not trigger. 
Is triggering timer from javascript valid?

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
var myVar; 
$(document).ready(function () { 
    myFunction();
    window.location.href = "https://www.google.com";
});

function myFunction() { 
    myVar = setTimeout(alertFunc, 6000);
}

function alertFunc() { 
    alert("Hello!");
}
```